# What are some of the most common uses of Exception handling?

Tags: java

Im trying to get a better understanding of when it's best to use exception handling.  I cant't fully get a grasp on it, so figured if I can get some common examples, it will help me to understand the whens/whys.

If people could give examples of the most common uses for THEM, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check Robert Sebesta's take on exception handling: http://www.cs.ndsu.nodak.edu/~slator/html/CS372/sebesta-pdf/13.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Exception handling is the ability of a program to intercept run-time errors, take corrective measures, and then continue.

One common use for exception handling could be found when you are attempting to open a file. If a file does not exist it could potentially make the program unreliable. In order to circumvent that issue you need to utilize an Exception handler. Here is a method that opens a text file that I made for an old project.

```
public static void openFile() {
    JFileChooser getData = new JFileChooser();
    if ( getData.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        java.io.File            dataSheet = getData.getSelectedFile();
        try {
            input =                                 new Scanner (dataSheet);
        }
        catch ( Exception e ) {
            GenerateInterface.theGame.printOutput( "File does not exist." );
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see if the file does not exist it catches (intercepts) the error, then it continues by running the code I wrote for that exception.

Answer (score 0):

There are errors that can happen during a program's execution that will cause your program to close prematurely.

Different kinds of errors throw different kinds of exceptions, which can/must be handled based on the situation.

This is a pretty basic concept though and is covered at length in many places, just Google it.

Answer (score 0):

An **exception** is an event that occurs during the execution of a program that disrupts the normal flow of instructions. So  you have to handle exception. 
See below simple test example:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a;
        String b="10";// if random input then it may be string instead of number
        try
        {
        a=Integer.parseInt(b);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

if **b** variable's value will be entered dynamically and someone enter alphabet value instead of integer then it throws `java.lang.NumberFormatException` so to be safe side, such code you have to put in **try catch** block.

As you see , no need to put variables declaration code in **try catch** block.